# Translate points from one coordinate origin to another

Tags: math, coordinates, coordinate-systems

So I want to translate three points between different pivots in a 10x10 coordinate system

to visualize what I want:

this is my first coordinate system

[image]

translate to:

[image]

now the points have to stay on the same spot between the different systems so only the coordinates for these points should change. First I thought I should just add the previous origin to the translated coordinates it would work for A and B but C is just different maybe im using a wrong formula or something

please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this:

```
originX = 0;
originY = 0;

A(x + originX, y + originY);
B(x + originX, y + originY);
C(x + originX, y + originY);
```

Here, x is where you want to place each one on the X axis, and y is where you want to place each one on the Y axis. and originX/Y is the origin point of your grid ((0, 0) in the first diagram and (5, 5) in the second). I don't know what you'r code is or even what language it is in (though i'm guessing python by your name), so i can't really help much more. You should tag your questions with the language your code is in and include some or all of it in your question to make answering easier (in most cases). Good luck!